# How to do INNER JOIN to another queryset/query

Tags: python, django

I have a problem with Django ORM. I have a model Weather:

```
    class Weather(models.Model):
        city = models.ForeignKey(City, verbose_name='Город', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        temperature = models.FloatField('Температура')
        source = models.CharField('Источник', max_length=100)
        date = models.DateTimeField('Дата и время')
```

I want to get actual weather from every source for every city. I created sql query for that but I don't understand how to do it with Django ORM.

Query:

```
SELECT * FROM api_weather t1 INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(date) AS latest_date, city_id, source FROM api_weather WHERE date<='2019-07-04 15:50' GROUP BY city_id, source
) t2
ON t1.city_id = t2.city_id AND t1.source = t2.source AND t1.date = t2.latest_date
```

I realized how to do

```
SELECT MAX(date) AS latest_date, city_id, source FROM api_weather WHERE date<='2019-07-04 15:50' GROUP BY city_id, source
```

with Django ORM, it's

```
Weather.objects.filter(date__lte=datetime.datetime.now()).values('city_id', 'source').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

but I don't understand how to do INNER JOIN from model Weather to this query.

Answer (score 0):

```
Weather.objects.values('city', 'source', 'temperature').annotate(latest_date=Max('date'))
```

Comment: I need actual weather, not max temperature